# onappear in sikuli - java

Tags: java, sikuli

I am looking for the application of "onappear" along with click, wherein I want to click on the captured GUI  once it appears.

I know this can be done using "wait" and then using "click", but then I have to statically feed in the wait time, which I wish to avoid.

Is there a way to use "onappear" and "click" together?
If not can somebody please come up with a solution to wait for a GUI and clicking it thereafter (dynamic wait)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a built-in solution, but you could write your own simple definition to do it. This doesn't use onAppear specifically, but I think it might accomplish your purpose.

In python:

```
def waitClick(myImage):
    time = 0
    while time < 30:
        if not myRegion.exists(myImage):
            wait(.5)
            time += 1
        else:
            click(myImage)
            break
```

This will check every half second for your image to appear, for 15 seconds. When it does appear, it will click the image, and then terminate the loop. Would something like this be helpful?